# How to add variable matching hostname

Tags: bash, expect

Im trying to make a expect script that log on to a list of cisco hosts and execute a command that include a variable that is a ip address matching the host.

I have a file (host_list) with hostnames and ip addresses formated like this :

```
host1.someplace.com 192.168.0.1
host2.otherplace.com 192.168.0.2
host3.thisplace.com 192.168.0.3
etc
```

The .sh script look like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
 # Collect the current user's ssh password file to copy.
 echo -n "Enter the SSH password for $(whoami) : "
 read -s -e password
 echo -ne '\n'
 echo -n "Enter the command  : " 
 read -e command
 echo -ne '\n'

for device in `cat host_list | awk '{print $1}'`; do 
./configure-cisco.exp $device $password "$command" ;
 done
```

The .exp script :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Set variables
 set hostname [lindex $argv 0]
 set username $env(USER)
 set password [lindex $argv 1]
 set command  [lindex $argv 2]
 set timeout 1
# Log results
 log_file -a ~/log/results.log

# Announce which device we are working on and at what time
 send_user "\n"
 send_user ">>>>>  Working on $hostname @ [exec date] <<<<<\n"
 send_user "\n"

 spawn ssh $hostname
 expect "password:"
 send "$password\n"
 expect "*$"
 send "$command\n"
 expect "*$"
 exit
```

What i need is to match the ip address to the host and put it in a variable to be used with `send "$command\n"`.

Something like : `send "$command $ipaddress\n"`

The `$command` will be different over time, but in the live situation it will be.

```
event manager environment PRIMARY_BGP_NEIGHBOR
```

And the `$ipaddress` must match the host the scrip is connected to.

I test this with ssh to different linux host before i execute the script towards a live cisco environment, where i will use telnet to connect, but the functionality should be the same.

Comment: Why using expect at all ? [Better use ssh key pairs instead of needing typing passwords](https://gist.github.com/sputnick-dev/65f023c2ac8c2318dcb2563199ec663a)

Comment: You could use DNS and or your local host file and never need the ip.  But if you must: `hostip=$(grep <HOST> host_list | awk '{print $2})`   assuming host names are unique through the host_list file.

Comment: ssh is not to be used at all when making it work in a live environment. telnet is the only option to connect to the cisco devices.
===========

Hostnames are unique in the host_list file and it must be this way since it is on cisco devises in a ISP network.

Comment: Pub-key auth for SSH is not always an option for some users. And even the key can have a passphrase if security is real concern. Then ssh-agent?

Comment: There's some good perl library to wrap telnet command: Net-Telnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the .sh:

```
names=()
ips=()
n=0
while read name ip; do
  [[ -z $ip ]] && continue
  names[n]=$name
  ips[n]=$ip
  ((++n))
done < hostfile

for ((i=0; i<n; ++i)); do
  script.exp ${names[i]} ${ips[i]} $device "$passwd"
done
```

Comment: I cant get this to work.
Get "line 30: syntax error: unexpected end of file"

There is only 29 lines in the file.......

Could you explain what this does so i might see whats wrong?

Comment: Sorry there's a typo. `((++n)` should be `((++n))`. Updated.

Comment: Make sure you quote the shell variables, particularly the password.

Comment: **Fantastic! That did the trick! :-)** @EmilyE.

Now i need to understand what that code does so i can use it in other ways and learn more.